# how searchview work for listView in android?

Tags: android

suppose i have listview content like this.

```
------------------------------------------------------
TextView             TextView
--------------------------------------------------
TextView             TextView
----------------------------------------------------
TextView             TextView
-------------------------------------------------------
TextView             TextView
----------------------------------------------------
```

so is it possible to search my search content on each component of listview using searchview in android.

for example if i type in searchview "bob". then it will check bob in all 4 textview and give a updated result to you....

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's possible, and it can be achieved using SearchView. Your Adapter should Implement Filterable and it's getFilter() method will have your filtering criteria.

I am using SearchView in ActionBar for showing this functionality.

My Activity -

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockListActivity implements OnQueryTextListener {

    private MyMessage myMessage; // list item, which is a model class in my case
    private ListView mListView;
    private MessageAdapter mAdapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.layout_containing_listView);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        //Create the search view
        SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

        mListView = getListView();
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        setupSearchView(searchView);

        menu.add(0, 1, 1, null)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void setupSearchView(SearchView mSearchView) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Sender");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Adapter -

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    List<MyMessage> msgsList;
    List<MyMessage> mOriginalValues;
    List<String> mListItem; // any key of MyMessage Model Class
    MyMessage message;

    public MessageAdapter(List<MyMessage> msgList) {
        super();
        this.msgsList = msgList;
    }

    …. 
    ….
    …

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        /**
         * A filter object which will
         * filter message key
         * */
        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                msgsList = (List<MyMessage>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values. Only filtered values will be shown on the list 
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation for publishing

                List<MyMessage> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<MyMessage>();

                if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<MyMessage>(msgsList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                }

                if(mListItem == null){
                    mListItem = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for(MyMessage message : mOriginalValues){
                        mListItem.add(message.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * 
                 *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                 *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                 *
                 **/

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    /* CONTRACT FOR IMPLEMENTING FILTER : set the Original values to result which will be returned for publishing */
                    results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                    results.values = mOriginalValues;
                } else {
                    /* Do the filtering */
                    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for (int i = 0; i < mListItem.size(); i++) {
                        String data = mListItem.get(i);
                        if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                            FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                        }
                    }    

                    // set the Filtered result to return
                    results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                    results.values = FilteredArrList;
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

For convenience, my model class MyMessage -

```
public class MyMessage implements Parcelable{

    private String messageKey = "";
    private String key = "";
    private String key2 = "";

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

You need to do something like this:

```
 public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchViewFilterMode";

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    @TargetApi(11)
    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.cheese_hunt_hint));
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```